# $routeParams.param returns undefined

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I've configured a route and try to pass parameters to a controller:

**app.js**

```
.config(function($stateProvider, $urlRouterProvider) {
  $stateProvider
    .state('spot', {
      url: "/spot/:param",
      templateUrl: "templates/spot.html",
      controller: "SpotCtrl"
    });
    $urlRouterProvider.otherwise('/');
});
```

controller:

```
angular.module('spotx.controllers')
  .controller('SpotCtrl', ['$scope', '$routeParams',
    function($scope, $routeParams) {

  $scope.do = function() {
    console.log($routeParams.param);
  };

}])
```

The url is **/#/spot/1111**, but if I fire the do-function I get *undefined* in the console.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`$routeParams` is for ngRoute router not angular-ui-router.

You need `$stateParams` ... see ui router docs

I'm suprised you aren't getting an unknown provider error unless you have both router scripts included in page and have `ngRoute` also injected in a module

Comment: I've included angular-route.min.js and injected ngRoute to my app.

Comment: So you have 2 routers in page? No need for `ngRoute` if using ui router

Comment: Where do you know that I am using UI router?

Comment: Because it uses `$stateProvider` and `ngRoute` uses `$routeProvider`. They are not interchangeable other than swapping scripts and injections

Comment: Then `$stateProvider` would throw error. Non of this is making sense

Comment: I am using Ionic  - maybe it is included in the ionic.bundle.js or in the angular-resources.min.js - How to get the URL parameters with the UI router? Without ngRoute...

Comment: did you try the answer I gave you?

Comment: So should be able to back out `ngRoute` from your page